# Changing the default Sails public folder

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I know from experience that Sails creates a ./.tmp/public/ folder from where it serves all my files. I'd like to change it to just ./public/

I read a GitHub issue that said I could do it in config/local.js, but that doesn't seem to be working. Here's the GitHub issue: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/709

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks.

As to why I'm trying to do this, it's because I'm actually trying to work with Sails and Parse to build a simple test application. Since Parse looks in the ./public/ directory by default and I couldn't find a way to change this behaviour, I'm trying to configure Sails.

Comment: you do in local.js  sails.config.paths.public = '/path/of/your/choice' ?  what sails version you used?

Comment: I'm using 0.11.
I tried doing what you suggested, but it does not seem to work in the latest version. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using out of the box Grunt tasks, then you will need to go through and edit those tasks in `<root>/tasks/config`, there does not seem to be an global config variable for this, so you might have touch each file.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/tasks/config

Comment: I was afraid of this, but it looks like the only way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Ya, its a little tedious, but the files are short and straight forward. It would probably be worth a PR to put all this in a config variable.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file config/paths.js with the value:

module.exports.paths = {
    'public': 'assets/'};

Comment: can we add multiple folders as public folders? I could add one but the public key won't allow an array

Comment: one public folder that can include multiple public folder

Answer (score 2):

As in the mentioned issue report it can either be done in the `.sailsrc` file

```
{
  "paths": {
    "public": "bar/foo"
  } 
}
```

or if you launch sails in your own app (no using `sails lift`)

```
var Sails = require('sails');
Sails.lift({
  paths: { public: 'mydir/pub' }, // relative to appDir
}, function(err, server) {});
```

Comment: This worked for me, I need to run the Angular app from Sails app. It helped. Thanks.